# ¿Cómo hago para que las colisiones entre objetos tengan alguna consecuencia en SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, game, spritekit

Soy novato en la programación, espero que podáis ayudarme. Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño juego al estilo "Flappy Bird" a modo de práctica y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema:

Resulta que no consigo que las colisiones entre los objetos produzcan ningún efecto (como hacer un game over, activar un contador, etc.).
Le he dado mil vuelta y quizá es que no he entendido bien el tema de las colisiones en SpriteKit, pero no consigo dar con el problema.

GameScene.swift:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

//Enum con las distintas colisiones
enum Collisions: UInt32 {
    case Fly = 1
    case Object = 2
    case Breach = 4
}

//Variables de todos los elementos del juego
var fly = SKSpriteNode()
var background = SKSpriteNode()
var land = SKSpriteNode()
var tube1 = SKSpriteNode()
var tube2 = SKSpriteNode()
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var score = 0
var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()
var gameOver = false
var timer = Timer()
var play = false


func setupGame() {

    //MOSCA:
    //Texturas
    let flyTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "fly1")
    let flyTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "fly2")
    let flyTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "fly3")
    //Movimiento
    let animationFly = SKAction.animate(with: [flyTexture1,flyTexture2, flyTexture3], timePerFrame: 0.1)
    let moveFly = SKAction.repeatForever(animationFly)
    fly = SKSpriteNode(texture: flyTexture1)
    fly.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY)
    fly.zPosition = -1
    fly.run(moveFly)
    //Físicas
    fly.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: flyTexture1.size().height / 2)
    fly.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    fly.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    fly.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = Collisions.Fly.rawValue
    fly.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue | Collisions.Fly.rawValue
    fly.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue | Collisions.Breach.rawValue

    self.addChild(fly)

    //FONDO:
    //Textura
    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background")
    //Animación para de movimiento constante
    let backgroundMove1 = SKAction.moveBy(x: -backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 8)
    let backgroundMove2 = SKAction.moveBy(x: backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
    let backgroundAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([backgroundMove1, backgroundMove2]))

    //Bucle con el que situamos la imagen repetidamente en la pantalla
    var i : CGFloat = 0
    while i < 5 + self.frame.size.width / (backgroundTexture.size().width) {
        background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: i * backgroundTexture.size().width, y: -self.frame.midY)
        background.size.height = self.size.height
        background.run(backgroundAnimation)
        background.zPosition = -2
        self.addChild(background)

        i += 1
    }

    //SUELO:
    //Textura
    let landTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "land")
    //Animación para de movimiento constante
    let landMove1 = SKAction.moveBy(x: -landTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 2)
    let landMove2 = SKAction.moveBy(x: landTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
    let landAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([landMove1, landMove2]))

    //Bucle con el que situamos la imagen repetidamente en la pantalla
    var j : CGFloat = 0
    while j < 5 + self.frame.size.width / (landTexture.size().width) {
        land = SKSpriteNode(texture: landTexture)
        land.position = CGPoint(x: j * land.size.width - 500, y: -self.size.height / 2)

        land.run(landAnimation)

        land.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: landTexture.size().height))
        land.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

        land.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue
        land.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue
        land.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = Collisions.Fly.rawValue

        land.zPosition = -1
        self.addChild(land)

        j += 1

    }

    //Puntuación
    scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 70)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)


}

//Crear los tubos y su aparición aleatoria
  @objc func createTube(){
    //TUBOS:

    let breachHeight = UInt(self.frame.size.height / 3)
    let y = UInt(arc4random()) % breachHeight



    //Texturas
    let tubeTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "tube1")
    let tubeTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "tube2")


    let tubeGroup = SKNode()


    tubeGroup.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + 300, y: self.frame.minY)

    tubeGroup.zPosition = -1


    tube1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: tubeTexture1)
    tube1.size.height = self.frame.size.height / 1.5
    tube1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(y))
    tube1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tube1.size)
    tube1.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    tube1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue
    tube1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue
    tube1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = Collisions.Fly.rawValue


    tubeGroup.addChild(tube1)



    tube2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: tubeTexture2)
    tube2.size.height = self.frame.size.height / 1.5
    tube2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(y) + tube1.size.height + CGFloat(breachHeight))
    tube2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: tube2.size)
    tube2.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    tube2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue
    tube2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = Collisions.Object.rawValue
    tube2.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = Collisions.Fly.rawValue

    tubeGroup.addChild(tube2)


    let tubeMove = SKAction.moveBy(x: -2 * self.frame.width, y: 0.0, duration: TimeInterval(8))

    let tubeSequence = SKAction.sequence([tubeMove])

    tubeGroup.run(tubeSequence)


    //Añadir brecha
    let breach = SKNode()
    breach.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(y) + tube1.size.height)


    //Añadir las físicas
    breach.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: tubeTexture1.size().width, height: CGFloat(breachHeight)))
    breach.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    breach.run(tubeMove)
    breach.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collisions.Breach.rawValue
    breach.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Collisions.Breach.rawValue
    breach.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collisions.Fly.rawValue

    tubeGroup.addChild(breach)

    self.addChild(tubeGroup)


 }

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    //Añadimos la física al mundo
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.0)

    //Llamamos a la función para la configuración del juego
    setupGame()


}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if !gameOver{
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == Collisions.Breach.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == Collisions.Breach.rawValue {

            score += 1
            scoreLabel.text = String(score)

        }else{

            //Añadir game over
            gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
            gameOverLabel.fontSize = 50
            gameOverLabel.text = "Game Over! Pulsa para comenzar"
            gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
            self.addChild(gameOverLabel)
            self.speed = 0
            gameOver = true
            play = false
            timer.invalidate()

        }
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

     if !gameOver {

     if !play {

     createTube()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.createTube), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     play = true
     }
     fly.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
     fly.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 60))
     fly.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true


     } else {

     score = 0
     self.speed = 1
     gameOver = false
     self.removeAllChildren()
     setupGame()
     }

}

func rotacion(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat, valor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    if valor > max {
        return max

    }else if valor < min {
        return min

    }else {
        return valor

    }
}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    fly.zRotation = self.rotacion(min: -0.5, max: 0.5, valor: (fly.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)! * (fly.physicsBody!.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001))

  }
}
```

PD: Si necesitáis algún otro dato no dudéis en preguntar o si hay alguna otra crítica constructiva que me queráis hacer será bienvenida.

Muchísimas gracias por vuestro tiempo!!!

Comment: Seguramente el problema esté en el if que hay en la función "didBegin". Pero no doy con la clave. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Has declarado tu clase como ContactDelegate, además de hacer que conforme al protocolo?

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Añádelo en didMoveToView()

Comment: Siento muchísimo la tardanza en contestar. Ya tenía este proyecto abandonado.
Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, eso ha solucionado el problema.
Ahora solo queda arreglar algún que otro fallo menor en el código.

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado